# Cosa significa "le aveva tenuto il sellino" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Chi invece buttava le mani sul piano solo per chiasso e cantava e poi smetteva malamente, era Silvia. Silvia era piú giovane di un anno o due, e certe volte faceva ancora le scale di corsa – quell’anno andava in bicicletta e il figlio del capostazione **le aveva tenuto il sellino**.

So che "sellino" è la sella della bicicletta, ma non capisco il significato dell'espressione "le aveva tenuto il sellino" nell'ultima frase di questo brano. Alla voce "tenere" dei dizionari ci sono tantissime accezioni che non riesco a capacitarmi di quale sia quella adatta al testo sopra citato. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Comment: Potrebbe essere interpretato come *le aveva insegnato ad andare in bicicletta*.

Comment: Quanti anni ha Silvia in questo brano?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Più o meno vent’anni, forse un po' di più, ma non molto.

Comment: @egreg: Non capisco la tua interpretazione? In che senso "tenere il sellino" sarebbe insegnare ad andare in bicicletta?

Comment: @Charo Quando si insegna a qualcuno ad andare in bicicletta, è necessario dapprima reggergli la bici finché non imparano a stare in equilibrio da soli. Nella mia esperienza, il modo più semplice (e meno fastidioso per il ciclista) è [reggerla per il sellino](https://c8.alamy.com/compit/c428fy/madre-nel-giardino-sul-retro-insegnare-a-suo-figlio-ad-andare-in-bicicletta-c428fy.jpg)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Anch'io avevo pensato che il significato di "tenere" in questo contesto fosse forse quello di "reggere". Cioè, il figlio del capostazione aveva aiutato Silvia a salire o a mantenersi sulla bicicletta reggendola dal sellino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per insegnare a un adulto come andare in bicicletta, il metodo più semplice e usato è di reggere la bicicletta per il sellino (nella parte posteriore, larga, con la mano sotto); chi deve imparare può così togliere i piedi da terra e abituarsi alla sensazione. Il sellino è più o meno al centro della bicicletta (in senso longitudinale), quindi non si fa alcuna fatica a reggerla anche con il peso del ciclista e si può spingerla in avanti e seguirla durante le prime pedalate.

Il tempo usato (*le aveva tenuto il sellino*) indica che l'avvenimento è precedente al fatto che Silvia, quell'anno, andasse in bicicletta: dunque Silvia poteva andare perché il figlio del capostazione le aveva insegnato.